# Reduce Pandas / Dask DataFrame memory usage to scale up simulation

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, simulation, dask

I have a simulation pipeline where I run experiments on patients. Everything's in Python (SciPy, Numpy, Pandas, etc.) in a local Docker container running on 2017 MacBook Pro (3.5 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7 and 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3).

The **experiments** DataFrame looks like this:

```
       trial  experiment  observation  compound     value
0          1          10            1         4  7.578612
1          7           8            1         4  1.751288
2         11           7            1         4  0.754702
3         30           6            1         4  7.762336
4         35           4            1         3  3.613458
```

and here's the **patients** one:

```
       patient  compound    lab    unit  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3   metric_4
0        72070         7  lab_a  unit_c   1292774     44351      3454  17.219036
1        43025         3  lab_a  unit_b    661842     30200      6147  11.882615
2        45878         8  lab_b  unit_b    292885     30928      7864  28.959206
3          697         7  lab_a  unit_a   1352669     81372      3769   3.728837
4        51402         8  lab_a  unit_c    517981     48154       381  45.606934
```

At the end of this simulation, I generate statistics on the individual observation. To get there, I merge both DataFrames to get the individual results (inner merge on **compound**). Both DataFrames are currently relatively small (50,000 rows for **patients** and 15,000 rows for **experiments**) but I'm trying to increase the size of the simulation (10x the number of experiments), which gets the simulation to crash.

### 1 - Initial Approach

I started by doing a simple Pandas merge ("inner" is the default)

```
import pandas as pd
results = pd.merge(experiments, patients, on="compound")

results

          trial experiment  observation compound     value  patient    lab    unit  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3   metric_4
0             1         10            1        4  7.578612    11437  lab_a  unit_b   1022481     24955      7312  43.395134
1             1         10            1        4  7.578612    60952  lab_a  unit_c    873872     98759      1348   5.580664
2             1         10            1        4  7.578612    41207  lab_a  unit_b    421455     88188      9705  27.077997
3             1         10            1        4  7.578612    62537  lab_a  unit_a    645139     24159      6014   3.610864
4             1         10            1        4  7.578612    59984  lab_a  unit_c   1176892     96816      6099  45.588840
...         ...        ...          ...      ...       ...      ...    ...     ...       ...       ...       ...        ...
83320766  99898          5            1        5  6.272213    33903  lab_a  unit_b    894670     98514      6620   9.320307
...
```

I get **83.34M** rows as a results (which is what I want). The simulation took 01:04 to run and 7.45 GB of RAM (using `results.info(memory_usage="deep"`).

### 2 - Reduce DataFrame memory usage

I then changed downcasted the default data types to reduce the memory usage of both DataFrames.

```
experiments_schema = {
    "trial": "uint32",
    "experiment": "category",
    "observation": "uint8",
    "compound": "category",
    "value": "float32"
}

patients_schema = {
    "patient": "uint32",
    "compound": "category",
    "lab": "category",
    "unit": "category",
    "metric_1": "uint64",
    "metric_2": "uint32",
    "metric_3": "uint32",
    "metric_4": "float32",
}

experiments = experiments.astype(experiments_schema)
patients = patients.astype(patients_schema)
```

As expected, I get the same number of rows. The simulation took a bit less time to run (00:58) but used less than half RAM (3.49 GB).

### 3 - Reduce runtime with Dask

I then replaced my Pandas merge with a Dask one.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
results = dd.merge(experiments, patients, on="compound", how="inner")
```

Again, same number of rows. The simulation only took 00:26 to run and used 3.49 GB of memory.

---

### What to do next to improve the simulation performance / scale?

I need to run 150,000 experiments (10x more) on the same 50,000 patients. If I run this on my machine it'll just run out of memory with an error 137 (and I've maxed the Mac docker desktop settings to use as much RAM as possible). What can I do to run the simulation with 10x experiments?

- Should I expand Dask usage to capture the next steps of my pipeline and only do a `results.compute()` at the very end?
- Should I look into Cython or Numba implementations of the merge operation?
- Should I store to disk?
- Any other idea (except Spark / distributed workflow as everything's expected to be local)?

Thanks

---

**Edit**: here's a short script to regenerate sample data (if needed)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng()

experiment_count = 15000
experiments = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "trial": np.sort(rng.choice(a=100000, size=experiment_count, replace=False)),
        "experiment": rng.choice(a=[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], size=experiment_count, replace=True),
        "observation": rng.choice(a=[1, 2, 3], size=experiment_count, p=[0.9, 0.09, 0.01], replace=True),
        "compound": rng.choice(a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], size=experiment_count, replace=True),
        "value": 10*rng.random(size=experiment_count, dtype='float32')
    }
)

patient_pool = 50000
patients = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "patient": rng.choice(a=75000, size=patient_pool, replace=False),
        "compound": rng.choice(a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], size=patient_pool, replace=True),
        "lab": rng.choice(a=["lab_a", "lab_b", "lab_c"], size=patient_pool, p=[0.6, 0.3, 0.1], replace=True),
        "unit": rng.choice(a=["unit_a", "unit_b", "unit_c"], size=patient_pool, p=[0.3, 0.4, 0.3], replace=True),
        "metric_1": rng.choice(a=1500000, size=patient_pool, replace=True),
        "metric_2": rng.choice(a=100000, size=patient_pool, replace=True),
        "metric_3": rng.choice(a=10000, size=patient_pool, replace=True),
        "metric_4": 50*rng.random(size=patient_pool, dtype='float32'),
    }
)
```

Comment: The question is what do you want to do with `results` dataframe?

Comment: In the data you present, every patient takes part in every trail of the compound they are assigned. That's 165 trails pr. patient. When you scale up, it will be more than 1500 trials on each patient. Are you sure you intend to scale that way?

Comment: @Corralien there are two extra steps in that simulation pipeline: (1) filter results by "experiment" to add extra 3 extra columns (random draw from a SciPy distribution, product of 3 columns, and min of two columns) then concatenate in a new DataFrame, and (2) final groupby where the aggregation involves a count and two sums depending on the columns.

Comment: @SørenGroveVejlstrup - yes, I'm looking at rare outcome realizations so I need to increase the number of experiments to increase the level of details in those simulations

Comment: This is probably not very useful, but in case there are no cross-effects across patients (which seems to be true), then it might be possible to proceed with chunks of say 1000 patients at a time...

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev that's a good point - the only common denominator is indeed the compound. What I'll try is to do several dd.merge on filtered experiments (I have so far 8 of them) then the rest of my logic till I do the groupby. The benefit is that no single DataFrame should explode in terms of RAM as result. Probably that's also a good way to link that concept with npartitions in a dd.DataFrame then do a delayed result.compute()

Comment: Can you write to disk rather than call compute, the compute step is what is killing your memory. Merge is an intensive operation - you could run this and save a temporary copy to disk as a parquet file and then read it back in once complete as a dask dataframe and start working with the larger frame.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Given that the main bottleneck is the machine's RAM, creating a loop over the 8 categories of experiments means that no single DataFrame larger than 1 GB is kept in memory at any single time (once I'm done using them in my workflow, I force garbage collection with a `del intermediate_df` and `gc.collect()`). Long story short, I can now do 10x the initial setup and it takes roughly 5'. So we're getting close.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I'll try this soon, I've already rearranged the workflow to allow for a Dask-like setup like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general answer, summarising the comments:

In dealing with a large-scale problem in which there are no cross-effects or interdependencies among specific rows, one solution to get around RAM bottleneck is to chunks the rows.

In this particular example, if there are no cross-effects across patients, then chunking process into groups of 1000 patients at a time might work.

To apply dask: chunk-processing can be defined in a lazy manner using `dask.delayed` and execution scaled across multiple cores/machines.